# Обновление корзины чрез AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Нужно перезагрузить модуль корзины (запустить в нем код php) с помощью AJAX.
код блока корзины выглядит так:

```
<li class="active active_right" id='cart_content'>
                    <?php

                    if($_SESSION['total_sum']){
                        $total_sum = number_format($_SESSION['total_sum'], 0, ',', ' ');
                        echo "
                            <a class='dropdown-toggle ddt_right active_cart' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'><span class='cart_ruble_icon'></span><span class='right_menu_name' style='color: #ffffff'>$total_sum</span><span class='notification' style='display: block'>&nbsp;&nbsp;$_SESSION[total_quantity]&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span class='cart_icon'></span></a>
                        ";
                    }else{
                        echo "
                            <a class='dropdown-toggle ddt_right' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'><span class='right_menu_name'>Корзина</span><span class='cart_icon'></span></a>
                        ";
                    }
                    ?>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu ddm_right_menu">
                        <li><span class="tr_up_right"></span></li>
                        <?php
                        if($_SESSION['total_quantity']){

                            echo "
                            <li><span class='cart_title' style='width: 936px'>Корзина</span></li>
                            <li><span class='cart_delimiter' style='width: 936px'></span></li>
                            <li>
                                <div class='cart_table_wrap'>
                                <table class='cart_table'>";
                                foreach($_SESSION['cart'] AS $key){
                                    $par_sum = number_format($key['par_sum'], 0, ',', ' ');
                                    $brand = brand($key['item_id']);
                                    $color_title = get_color_title($key['color_id']);
                                    echo "
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style='width: 85px; padding: 0 0 0 5px'><a href='?view=store_item&amp;parent=$key[item_par_id]&amp;category=$key[item_cat_id]&amp;item_id=$key[item_id]' class='cart_item_img' title='Перейти к карточке товара' style='background: url(http://torawhite.ru/files/store/goods_imgs/$key[item_id]/$key[color_id]/0.jpg) 50% no-repeat; background-size: cover'></a></td>
                                        <td style='padding: 0 0 0 10px'>
                                            <div class='cart_details'>
                                                <div class='cart_detail_wrap'>
                                                    <a href='?view=store_item&amp;parent=$key[item_par_id]&amp;category=$key[item_cat_id]&amp;item_id=$key[item_id]' target='_self' class='cart_item_link' title='Перейти к карточке товара'>$brand[brand_title]&nbsp;$key[item_title]</a>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class='cart_detail_wrap'>
                                                    <span style='background: url(http://torawhite.ru/files/store/color_imgs/$key[color_id].svg) 50% no-repeat; background-size: cover' class='cart_item_color' title='$color_title[color_title]'></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class='cart_detail_wrap'>";
                                                    if($key['measure']){
                                                        echo "<span class='cart_measure'>$key[measure]</span>";
                                                    }
                                                echo "</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style='padding: 0 0 0 10px; width: 140px'>
                                            <div class='cart_qty'>
                                                <span class='cart_minus' data-cart-item-par-id='$key[parameter_id]'><span></span></span>
                                                <span class='cart_qty_input_wrap'>
                                                    <input id='cart_input_$key[parameter_id]' type='text' value='$key[qty]' disabled title='Количество единиц товара' class='cart_item_counter' data-cart-item-qty='$key[stock_qty]'>
                                                </span>
                                                <span class='cart_plus' data-cart-item-par-id='$key[parameter_id]'><span></span></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style='padding: 0 0 0 10px; width: 140px'>
                                            <div style='display: block; float: right'><span class='cart_count_icon'></span><span class='cart_count'>$par_sum</span></div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style='width: 40px; padding: 0 0 0 10px'><div class='cart_fav' title='Отложить товар'><span></span></div></td>
                                        <td style='width: 40px; padding: 0 0 0 20px'><div class='cart_del' title='Удалить товар из корзины'><span></span></div></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    ";
                                }

                            echo"</table>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><span class='cart_delimiter'></span></li>

                        <li><table class='right_total_count_table'>
                                <tr >
                                    <td>Товаров:</td>
                                    <td>$_SESSION[total_quantity]</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Сумма:</td>
                                    <td><span class='right_total_count_sum_icon'></span><span>$total_sum</span></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table></li>
                        <li><div class='right_submit_wrap'>
                            <span class='right_submit'>ОФОРМИТЬ ЗАКАЗ</span>
                        </div></li>
                        ";
                        }else{
                            echo "
                            <li><span class='cart_title' style='width: 170px'>Корзина</span></li>
                            <li><span class='cart_delimiter' style='width: 170px'></span></li>
                            <li><span class='empty_cart'>Корзина пуста</span></li>
                        ";
                        }
                        ?>

                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Корзина реализована с помощью глобального массива $_SESSION.
Отправку данных товара делаю с помощью AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#add_to_cart').click(function(){

            var selected = $('.selected'); // Определяем переменную
            var color_section_id = selected.attr('data-color'); // Определяем переменную
            var select_body_item = $('#select_body_item_' + color_section_id + ' option:selected'); // Определяем переменную
            var parameter_id = select_body_item.val(); // Определяем переменную
            var input = $('.qty_input_wrap input'); // Определяем переменную
            var qty = input.val(); // Определяем переменную

            if(parameter_id != 0){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://store.torawhite.ru/",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: ({
                        cart: 'add_item',
                        par_id: parameter_id,
                        par_qty: qty,
                        success: function(){

                            $("#modal_window_cart_add").show();
                            setTimeout(function() { $("#modal_window_cart_add").hide(); }, 2000);

                        },
                        error: function(){

                        }
                    })

                });
            }else{
                $("#modal_window_cart_error").show();
                setTimeout(function() { $("#modal_window_cart_error").hide(); }, 2000);
            }

        });

    });
```

Но как в `success` запустить код корзины не понимаю.

Comment: Имхо это не правильный подход. По любому должен быть родной экшен, который добавляет товары в корзину, а в респонсе выдает готовый html для перерисовки этой самой корзины. Вот его и надо использовать, а не изобретать велосипед. Посмотрите через firebug какой экшен используется для корзины.

Comment: @AndrewGodin, добавление в корзину происходит следующим образом - через AJAX отправляются 3 параметра в обработчик: `cart` - по нему определяется, что нужно выполнить код добавления в корзину, `par_id` - это идентификатор параметра товара, `par_qty` - количество товара. Создаётся массив $_SESSION['cart'] с ключём, равным идентификатору товара, туда добавляется `qty` и вытаскиваются из базы все данные о товаре. Далее в цикле php этот массив выводится в корзину. Не пойму, о каком ещё вы экшене говорите